# How to send form data as json in angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to send my form data as json but not able to do so can any one help please....
my ts,

```
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    this.http.post(this.header1+'login', JSON.stringify(form), { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            if (response.json().error_code == 0) {
             //   console.log(response.json().data[0].profile_id);
                if (response.json().data[0].profile_id) {
                    localStorage.setItem('social', JSON.stringify(response.json().data[0]));
                }
                this.toastr.success('Loggedin successfully');
                this.router.navigate(['/demo/profile']);

            }
            else {
                this.toastr.error('Email or Password is wrong');
            }
        });


}
```

but i am not able to see any data going to server from network

Comment: did you check, that this.header1+'login' is a valid url?

Comment: Please add your fully code file.

Comment: yes it is a valid url i see 200ok

Comment: Did you actually call `.subscribe` on the `post` call, because you omit code after that?

Comment: i will post my code

Comment: your Content-Type should be 'application/json', but I guess you should see outgoing data anyway, if not your JSON.stringfy(form) is an empty string.

Comment: Gunter,i changed to it also but not able to see formdata directing to server

Answer (score 0):

i cleared it by including the following steps in my node.js

```
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        // Website you wish to allow to connect
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        // Request methods you wish to allow
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        // Request headers you wish to allow
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
        // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
        // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        // Pass to next layer of middleware
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, application/json');
        next();
    });
```

Comment: We could have helped you with that, if you told us, that you're getting CORS errors.